# Custom save button that handles server side form validation

Tags: button, react-admin, onerror

I'm on React Admin 4.2.4 and I have a custom save button where I would like it to detect the error from the API response and update the field in red as it does with normal form validation.

```
            <SaveButton
                variant="contained"
                id="createSave"
                alwaysEnable
                submitonenter="true"
                icon={<SaveIcon style={{ height: '20px', width: '20px' }} />}
                mutationOptions={{
                    onSuccess: (response) => {
                        refresh();
                        redirect('show', 'books', response.id);
                    },
                    onError: (error) => { notify(error.body.errors.username, {type: "error"}); }
                }}
                type="button"
            />
```

Everything works except getting the input field on the form to update with the red text. Is this doable?
I haven't been able to find out how I can do this on this RA version

Comment: Look at here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Validation.html#server-side-validation

Comment: That's where I started but it's for their latest version and doesn't work for 4.2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with the following:

```
 <SimpleForm onSubmit={save} 

const save = useCallback(
        async values => {
            try {
                await create('users', { data: values }, { returnPromise: true }).then(response => {
                    refresh();
                    redirect('show', 'users', response.id);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                if (error.body.errors) {
                    return error.body.errors;
                }
            }
        },
        [create, redirect, refresh]
    );
```

The trick was I couldn't have my custom save button as type "button", but I needed to redirect after submission.